# Back-projecting from 3x4 matrix to world coordianates

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry

I have a 3x4 projection matrix **P** that given a point in world coordinates (homogeneous) **w** =[x,y,z,1], projects the point into image space; **P*w=[x,y,w]** where **[x/w,y/w]** are pixel coordinates and **w** is interpreted as the signed distance to image plane.

I would like to be able to un-project a pixel back to world coordinates (as a ray w/ distance for specific point). For example to back-project pixels [0,0] and [width-1,height-1] etc to get view frustum corners in world coordinates.

I've added a **[0,0,0,1]** vector to the bottom of the **P** matrix to make it squared 4x4(homogeneous?) matrix, which I then inverted. The inverse matrix seems to work fine in few examples I've tried - but I don't understand why, or if it is a valid approach? Thanks!

Comment: The W-row of a perspective projection matrix is usually **[0, 0, -1, 0]** or **[0, 0, 1, 0]** (convention-dependent), which means **w = ±z**. In the overall transformation matrix **P** - (implicit) model * view * projection - this becomes a translation component (the offset of the camera in its own direction). Strongly suggest that you look up the definition of the view matrix as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is called a pinhole model.

Maybe this will help you understand what is going on:
[image]

The projection matrix M transforms any point from the 3D world (Rw) to the 2D image (Rim) following the equation s.(u,v) = M (x,y,z,1)

If you can get the invert of M, that is to say M^-1 such as (M^-1)M = Identity, then it seems pretty obvious to me that:

s.(u,v) = M (x,y,z,1)

<=> (M^-1).s.(u,v) = (M^-1).M.(x,y,z,1)

<=> (M^-1).s.(u,v) = Identity.(x,y,z,1)

<=>(M^-1).s.(u,v) = (x,y,z,1)

That is to say that (M^-1) transforms any point from the 2D image world to the 3D world.

Note the presence of the factor 's' because the projection operation is not injective : several points from the 3D world can be projected to the same 2D point.

Answer (score 0):

You have the equation P w = x, where P and x are known and you want to solve for w. The vector w=[×,y,z,1] only has 3 unknowns. The last value is a constant so you only need three equations. If you add an extra row [0,0,0,1] to your 3×4 matrix P to make it 4×4 and add an extra row to your vector x i.e., [x,y,w,1]^T you are ackowledging that last component of w is 1 (indeed forcing the last componenet to be 1), so the new extra rows added did not change anything at all, justcomplete the degrees of freedom needed to invert P.